# How to build a pricing model for property rental service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regression

I am building a property rental service, and I need to find a way to **calculate the *right* price** /night for booking a room.

The specifications are :

**Owners can choose pricing rules such as :**

> « *the minimum price is 100$ / night* » **or** « *1 week in august should cost 3000$* » **or** « *during Easter holidays the price should be 200$ / night* »

**Guests will ask:**

> « *what is the cost for renting from the 1st of may to the 14th of may ?* »

**Do you know any tool that could help me ?** Or ideas on how I could build it ?

I would prefer the model to be coherent (and continuous), so I was thinking it could be a function `price(start_date, end_date)` obtained with some regression, but I would't know how to implement it.

*NB: my app is in rails, but I am happy to use python, matlab, R*

Comment: It's a bit unclear, if it's neither august nor easter holidays is the price always 100$? anyway what stops you from coding this business rules in Ruby?

Comment: exactly, some dates do not have a price, and the model would "fill the gaps". From the owner input, it will guess the "right" price for dates with no user input-ed prices

Answer (score 1):

That's a rough draft that could be optimized in many ways but I would do something like that:

```
# New model with the following attributes:
# room_id, begin_date, end_date, price
class Constraint < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
  validate :one_constraint_per_date

  def one_constraint_per_date
    # create a constraint to avoid having two constraint on the same date
  end
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :constraints

  # Price engine
  def price(date)
    prev_constraint = prev_constraint(date)
    next_constraint = next_constraint(date)

    # if there are no constraint when can't determine the price
    if prev_constraint.nil? && next_constraint.nil?
      nil
    # if there was no previous constraint, the will be the same as the next constraint
    elsif prev_constraint.nil?
      next_constraint.price
    # if there are no future constraint, the will be the same as the previous constraint
    elsif next_constraint.nil?
      prev_constraint.price
    # if date is included in a constraint, the price is the price of the constraint
    elsif prev_constraint == next_constraint
      next_constraint.price
    # if date is between two constraints, we need to calculate the price
    else
      numerator = (prev_constraint.end_date..date).count
      denominator = (prev_constraint.end_date..next_constraint.begin_date).count
      ratio = numerator.fdiv(denominator)

      prev_constraint.price * (1 - ratio) + next_constraint.price * ratio
    end
  end

  # Find the last constraint beginning before the specified date
  def prev_constraint(date)
    constraints
      .select { |c| c.begin_date.before?(date) }
      .max { |c| c.begin_date }
  end

  # Find the first constraint ending after the specified date
  def next_constraint(date)
    constraints
      .select { |c| c.end_date.after?(date) }
      .min { |c| c.end_date }
  end
end
```

Comment: I updated my code. This time it's working because I have tested it :)

Comment: yes this is the first approach, a ratio basically; but it will not work in many cases. Moreover, the resulting model wouldn't be continuous, and kinda difficult to query

Comment: How is it not working in many cases? It actually answers  your question (and the model is definitely continuous as you can query it for any timestamp).

Comment: If you are not interested in the implementation but only in a model that takes into account weeks instead of days you should ask your question in the math forum ! Keep in mind that you need to ask question with a « reasonable » scope :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. And don’t hesitate to accept the answer !